# Make PhpStorm favor @param instead of type declaration when using generics

Tags: php, generics, phpstorm

In a [post on the software engineering forum](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/431444/how-to-enforce-matching-but-unknown-interfaces) me and the community agreed that one of my architecture problems might be best solved using generics. Since in PHP generics are only supported via doc tags, my interface declarations always have two param types hinted: The `@param` tag and the PHP type declaration:

```
<?php

/**
 * @template T of NodeInterface
 */
interface DirectedLinkInterface
{
    /**
     * @param T $startNode
     */
    public function setStartNode(NodeInterface $startNode);
}
```

The problem is that whenever I use PHP's type declaration, PhpStorm ignores the more specific template variable.

Example:

I have a class that implements a specific version of the generic interface:

```
/**
 * @template-implements DirectedLinkInterface<DrawActionNode>
 */
class DirectedImageProcessingLink implements DirectedLinkInterface, FollowLinkInterface
{
    /**
     * @param DrawActionNode $startNode
     */
    public function setStartNode(NodeInterface $startNode): void
    {
        $this->startNode = $startNode;
    }

}
```

But when I use this class incorrectly, PhpStorm doesn't find the error, UNLESS I remove the type declarations:

```
$node = new WhateverNodeInterface();
$link = new DirectedImageProcessingLink();
$link->setStartNode($node); //No error found by PhpStorm
```

The above code will only be considered as faulty when I remove the type declaration, which I don't really want since a missing type declaration looks kind of old school php hackish, even if the hinted type is more generic than the PHPDoc.

```
<?php

/**
 * @template T of NodeInterface
 */
interface DirectedLinkInterface
{
    /**
     * @param T $startNode
     */
    public function setStartNode(/*No type declaration here*/ $startNode);
//Removing the type declaration as done above makes PhpStorm use the actual template 
//variable which, in the interface user's code, will be more specific and thus errors can be better found  
}
```

Do you know any way to convince PhpStorm to use the `@param` tag even though there is a type declaration? Or do you think that type declarations aren't that necessary if you use `@param` tags in combination with generics?